# How to change font size in Alex's Gorbatchev SyntaxHighlighter?

Tags: css, syntax-highlighting, syntaxhighlighter

I've tried to change the font sizes in [Alex Gorbatchev's SyntaxHighlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/) `.css` theme files, and used `font-size` in the `<pre>` tag, etc, but nothing happens. The size won't change.

**PD**: this is the [shCore.css](http://code.google.com/p/isuru89-syntax-highlight-compiled/source/browse/trunk/CSS/shCore.css?spec=svn8&r=8) main file.

Comment: Post the code. I for one have no idea what `Alex's Gorbatchev SyntaxHighlighter?` is

Comment: Post the code?... What?. Im asking for a simple feature that i guess it must be implemented somewhere in Alex's Gorbatchev SyntaxHighlighter. And why the downvote?

Comment: Why the downvote? Becuase this isn't the `Alex's Gorbatchev SyntaxHighlighter` support line. There is obviously a css file somewhere that controls font size. Post that.

Comment: Did you change the font size in this id?: `.syntaxhighlighter {
  width: 100% !important;
  margin: 1em 0 1em 0 !important;
  position: relative !important;
  overflow: auto !important;
  font-size: 1em !important;
}`

Comment: Yes. But didnt work. By the way, im reading the change logs, so i found that in much earlier version 2.0.320 it says: _"Removed font-size parameter option. SyntaxHighlighter font size is 1em, so any outer font size will be inherited by default."_ . So what that means?

Comment: @Wyvern666 post the code you tried to change in your question please.  Linking to a third party site for code is not good. What happens when that link dies or moves?

Comment: For anyone still running into this. Just wrap the `<pre>` or `<script>` tags that you use for syntax highlighting in a `<div class="syn_wrapper>` and style `.syn_wrapper { font-size:75%; }`. Since the syntax highlighted code gets its font size from the parent (see Wyvern666's comment above), and the parent has a reduced font size, the syntax highlighted code will end up with the reduced size too.

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of places to change the font size in the code sample you posted. Since it's not clear exactly which one you're targeting, start with this:

```
.syntaxhighlighter {
  width: 100% !important;
  margin: 1em 0 1em 0 !important;
  position: relative !important;
  overflow: auto !important;
  font-size: 2em !important; 
}
```

The sample above changes the `font-size` to 2em's

Comment: I tried all the places in that file, and didnt work.

Comment: I'm using version 3.0.83 of the code and I changed:
`.syntaxhighlighter {
...
font-size: 60% !important;
...}`

This for me achieved the result I was wanting (and what the OP asked for) - to get the font size looking more like what I needed.